# Standard linear solid model - dashpot "short out" at $t=0$

Tags: material-science, spring, drag, vibrations, polymers

My professor said that at $t=0$ the dashpot in standard linear solid is "short out". Why?

[image]

I know that the force of dashpot is ($u$ is the dislplacement):

$$F_{\eta}=\eta \space \frac{du}{dt}.$$

Comment: what do you/does your professor mean by "shot out" - preferably in mathematical terms?

Comment: Hi @Sanya, she said only short out and draws a short circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice to know what load conditions you're assuming at $t=0$. For example, are you assuming a step increase in force (e.g., a creep experiment)? A step increase in displacement (e.g., a stress relaxation experiment)? Harmonic oscillation (e.g., a complex modulus experiment)?

In general, however, for sudden actions at single time points (and for very high frequencies), dashpots act as if they have nearly infinite stiffness; in other words, you can idealize them as a rigid link when analyzing a system under these conditions. (In contrast, over long unchanging periods and for very low frequencies, dashpots act essentially as open connections.) Perhaps this is what your professor meant by "short out".

Comment: Hi @Chemomechanics, could you write any mathematical formula please? I would like to understand this behaviour mathematically. At t=0 there is a step of stress.

Comment: Sure; just integrate your constitutive equation: $u=F_\eta t/\eta$ for a single dashpot. (As noted, the displacement is zero at $t=0$, reflecting infinite stiffness at that time point.)